# How to use Excel's PV function when payments are made quarterly but rate is compounded semi-annually?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, finance

***Note:*** This is not a plead to help with my homework

Here's the question in a book, which I'm trying to solve using Excel's `PV` function:

> A £100 bond has one year to maturity. The bond pays 6% per year with
>   coupon payments made quarterly. The interest rate is 5.8% per year
>   with interest compounded semi-annually. Calculate the value of the
>   bond.

```
╔═══╦══════╦═════╦══════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║   ║  A   ║  B  ║    C     ║           D           ║
╠═══╬══════╬═════╬══════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║Period║ Amt ║    PV    ║       Formula         ║
║ 2 ║ 0.25 ║ 1.5 ║   1.4787 ║ =B2/(1+5.8%/2)^(A2*2) ║
║ 3 ║  0.5 ║ 1.5 ║   1.4577 ║ =B3/(1+5.8%/2)^(A3*2) ║
║ 4 ║ 0.75 ║ 1.5 ║   1.4370 ║ =B4/(1+5.8%/2)^(A4*2) ║
║ 5 ║    1 ║ 1.5 ║   1.4166 ║ =B5/(1+5.8%/2)^(A5*2) ║
║ 6 ║    1 ║ 100 ║  94.4429 ║ =B6/(1+5.8%/2)^(A6*2) ║
║ 7 ║      ║     ║          ║                       ║
║ 8 ║      ║ Val ║ 100.2330 ║ =SUM(C2:C6)           ║
╚═══╩══════╩═════╩══════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

I understand the formula, but I'm not able to use the `PV` function to get the result. Here's what I tried:

```
=PV(5.8%/2,4,1.5,100)
# Result: 94.78
```

As I understand,

- the first argument should be the rate (divided by the number of compoundings in a year)
- the second should be the number of periods (which in this case is 4 - 4 quarterly payments in a year)
- the annuity payment made during each period
- the future value paid / received after the payment of last annuity

I think the discrepancy has to do with the fact that the payments are made quarterly and the discount rate is compounded semi-annually; I don't understand it, though.

Comment: Do you have to use the `PV` function or be open to something else?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, I'm not doing this to accomplish some temporary task. I wanted to learn working with Excel's financial functions. So, I want to use `PV`. However, if you have any other method, please feel free to add it as an answer; it might give me more clarity.

Comment: Why don't you try this one, `=PV(5.8%/2,12/3,100)` where `5.8%/2` is semiannual rate, `4` is `4` payments in year (quarterly) & `100` is `PMT`, it returns `372.60`